# React: If statements inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with this for a while now, I'm building a page so the user can create forms dynamically I have one react component that creates the forms and one that renders it, I'm currently facing problems with editing the forms already created.

```
const GigApplicationRenderer = (props) => {
  const {
    questions,
    onSelectDelete,
    onSelectEdit,
    classes,
    theme,
    handleClickOpen,
    handleClose,
    open
  } = props;
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {questions.map((element, index) => (
        <div className={classes.li} key={element.title}>
          <Grid container spacing={24}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              {element.type === 'input' ? (
                <Paper index={index} className={classes.paper}>
                  <Title
                    onSelectEdit={onSelectEdit}
                    onSelectDelete={onSelectDelete}
                    element={element}
                    handleClose={handleClose}
                    open={open}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    className={classes.textField}
                    value=""
                    label="answer text"
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                </Paper>
              ) : element.type === 'radiobox' ? (
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <Title
                    onSelectEdit={onSelectEdit}
                    onSelectDelete={onSelectDelete}
                    element={element}
                    handleClose={handleClose}
                    open={open}
                  />
                  {element.options.map(option => (
                    <ListItem key={option} className={classes.itemsList}>
                      <RadioGroup>
                        <FormControlLabel
                          label={option}
                          value={option}
                          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
                        />
                      </RadioGroup>
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </Paper>
              ) : element.type === 'checkbox' ? (
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <Title
                    onSelectEdit={onSelectEdit}
                    onSelectDelete={onSelectDelete}
                    element={element}
                    handleClose={handleClose}
                    open={open}
                  />
                  {element.options.map(option => (
                    <ListItem key={option} className={classes.itemsList}>
                      <FormControlLabel
                        label={option}
                        value={option}
                        control={<Checkbox checked={false} color="primary" />}
                      />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                  <Divider light />
                </Paper>
              ) : null}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

this is the component that renders the code, it has some if statements that check the properties of the forms created and renders it accordingly.

this is the title component:

```
const Title = (props) => {
  const {
    element, onSelectDelete, onSelectEdit, index, handleClose, open
  } = props;
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
      {console.log(element.title)}
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={9}>
        <Typography style={{ textAlign: 'left' }} variant="subheading" gutterBottom>
          {element.title}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
        <Tooltip enterDelay={100} leaveDelay={100} placement="bottom" title="Edit">
          <IconButton onClick={onSelectEdit(element, index)} aria-label="Edit">
            <EditIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        <Tooltip enterDelay={100} leaveDelay={100} placement="bottom" title="Delete">
          <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
            <DeleteIcon onClick={onSelectDelete(element)} />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </Grid>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
blabla
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
            occasionally.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            // value={element.title}
            margin="dense"
            label="question title"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Save
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

I want it to open a dialog with the values of the element clicked so the user could edit it, the problem is that no matter which button was clicked, on the dialog, it always renders the last element of the form.

On the function `onSelectEdit` though, I get the correct element, I think it is happening because of the if statements of the first component.

the questions array look like this:

```
questions: [
      {
        title: 'Why do you want this job?',
        type: 'input'
      },
      {
        title: 'Do you know Javascript?',
        type: 'radiobox',
        options: ['yes', 'no']
      },
      {
        title: 'What techs your know?',
        type: 'checkbox',
        options: ['html', 'css']
      }
    ],
```

is there a way to render the correct element when the dialog opens?

I'm also open to any suggestion on how to accomplish this.

Comment: One thing I would recommend is to uncouple your nested ternaries. Its perfectly ok to have `{element.type === 'input' && (<Components..>) }` repeated on multiple blocks. Makes your code easier to read. And btw that's also how you can do conditionals.

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox.io of your code so that we can reproduce the issue?